# Wireless network keeps prompting for password, unable to connect on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, tp-link

I'm using a TP-Link Archer T4U AC1200 V1 USB adapter.
I'm on a fresh install of 16.04.6, and after running software update, installing a nVidia proprietary driver, I needed to install the driver for my USB WiFi adapter. I used the following driver and followed all the instructions in the [readme](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/blob/master/README.md) for [rtl8812AU_8821AU linux kernel driver for AC1200 (801.11ac) Wireless Dual-Band USB Adapter - GitHub](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/archive/master.zip)

However, while my USB adapter is now recognized, it cannot connect to any of my home networks: Lim Family Fibre, LIMYPfamily 1 and LIMYPfamily 2. The symptoms are when I connect to a network and enter the password, it attempts to connect but never does, then prompts for the password again, without saying that an incorrect password was entered and with the password field already filled. When I click enter, the cycle repeats(cannot connect, prompts again)

I tried this: [WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers)

I have [pasted](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WPMyy6CQhq/) the output of Wireless Info Script on pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

In your paste, we see this:

```
Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'LIMYPfamily1' [AC1]>
                    ESSID:"LIMYPfamily1"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie=dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2040050f20201000050f202
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=43/100  Signal level=47/100  
                    Extra:fm=0001
```

Most wireless drivers in Linux don't work very well with TKIP. In addition, it is the least secure of all the protocols available. This suggests that your routers are set to factory defaults which are neither as secure as possible nor Linux-friendly. I suggest a few tweaks.

WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Is there any improvement?